# error Failed to build iOS project. We ran "xcodebuild" command but it exited with error code 65. Don't have build inside ios folder

Tags: android, ios, reactjs, react-native, visual-studio

To debug build logs further, consider building your app with Xcode.app, by opening AwesomeProject.xcworkspace.
Command line invocation:
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace AwesomeProject.xcworkspace -configuration Debug -scheme AwesomeProject -destination id=89CDAF46-41A6-4C46-9DCD-449992C6222D

**I don't have build inside the ios folder. I tried various methods found on the internet and it is still not working. **

Answer (score -1):

You’ll have to do what the message says and open Xcode. Running it there should give a real error message.

Comment: I am trying to run in visual studio as I am trying to create a react native app. The android simulator runs fine but it gives problems with the ios simulator.

Comment: The react native commands still use the native tools to run the simulators. Since you’re getting errors from XCode, you’ll have to find out what the problem is by using XCode directly. After you fix whatever the issue is you can go back to using the command line in VS Code.

Comment: I think there is a problem with M1 chip. We fixed the issues following this tutorial https://khushwanttanwar.medium.com/xcode-12-compilation-errors-while-running-with-ios-14-simulators-5731c91326e9. 

Then after starting a new project, the issues remain the same.